# Get all anchors with attribute href = a,b or c with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to find all anchor elements which have the href attribute equals to value 'a', 'b' or 'c'

So far what I have done is:

```
values = ['a','b','c']
anchors = page.css('a')

anchors.each do |anchor|
  if values.include? anchor.attribute('href').value
    p "found it"
  end
end
```

Is there any way I can directly select those anchors without having to go through each of them later on?

Comment: Do you mean after you find them with the loop you show you want to save them for later access?

Comment: I am trying to find out a way that would let me do this: page.css('a').where(a['href'].includes?...) If you know what I mean...

Comment: Try `anchor_set = anchors.find { |anchor| values.include? anchor }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Nokogiri, you can always use xpath:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
  This is <a href="http://b.com">a link</a>
  This is <a href="http://a.com">another link</a>
</body>
</html>


noko_page.xpath("//a[@href='http://a.com' or @href= 'http://b.com']")



=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc9360be368 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc9360bdcd8 name="href" value="http://b.com">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc93618e93c "a link">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc93618dc08 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc93618d71c name="href" value="http://a.com">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc93618fd78 "another link">]>]
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS allows us to request multiple different selectors:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="a">a link</a>
    <a href="x">x link</a>
    <a href="b">b link</a>
    <a href="y">y link</a>
    <a href="c">c link</a>
  </body>  
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.search('*[href="a"], *[href="b"], *[href="c"]').each { |n| p n.to_html }
```

Running that returns:

```
"<a href=\"a\">a link</a>"
"<a href=\"b\">b link</a>"
"<a href=\"c\">c link</a>"
```

Comment: Very nice! Perhaps if I knew more CSS selectors, I wouldn't have to learn XPath ;)

Comment: CSS are more readable and quite powerful. I believe XPath is more comprehensive than CSS but they serve different purposes in their real-world uses; Nokogiri is using them to search DOMs, so using CSS is a convenience, whereas using XPath would be an expectation for a Nokogiri-type tool. Still, knowing CSS is a good thing; You'd use it extensively with HTML and styling pages, plus jQuery uses it, and that's probably the most common JavaScript library.